# Guitar Tab API?

Tags: c#, api

I was just curious if anyone has heard of any sort of API for guitar tabs?  The thought passed through my mind that it would be really neat if I could grab guitar tabs from the internet to bring into my C# app, but haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Does the tag "wpf" indicate you're looking for a WPF Control to display Guitar Tabs?

Comment: I'm using WPF for my UI design.  I think my main problem currently is just obtaining the guitar tab data.  I can't seem to find any data source for them.

Comment: I removed the wpf tag as it is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: define API? How would your program interact with the tab?

Comment: My program just needs to be able to retrieve and display the tab.

Comment: why is this guitar tab specific? all you need to do is display images in a C# app, whats so hard about that? am I missing something?

Comment: The guitar tabs are not images though.  They are just in the form of ASCII art.

Comment: why not convert them to images? that way you avoid "spider" hacks like everyone here seems to think is "standard" practice!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to read the repository of your choice.

You can also use [`System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) to read RSS feeds.

**EDIT**: Try scraping http://www.mxtabs.net/guitar_tabs/ using `WebRequest`.

You can write code that sends requests to the pages of that (or any other) website and parses the responses to extract information.

However, you might want to get their permission first.  They might even offer you an API.

Comment: LOL. Every guitar tab site I found has *Stairway to Heaven* as the first-listed tab. C'mon, people, there are *other* guitar songs in the world!

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but I believe that Chrisc is looking for a way to parse the tabs, not get them in the first place.

Comment: @Blaenk: from Chrisc's comment: "I think my main problem currently is just obtaining the guitar tab data"

Comment: Yeah the thought of trying to grab something directly from a webpage crossed my mind.  I've never done anything like that before though... and, I'm not quite sure how I would get to the correct tab page (e.g. highest rated tab)

Answer (score 3):

You should approach it from another angle.. Why isn't there a good data format to transfer guitar tab data? I mean, ASCII art is good but it is easily damaged, and it doesn't convery timing information well.

If you could come up with a format that could reach critical mass, that would be a good thing.

Comment: Moose, that is something that I might ponder over in the near future.  But, for now, I don't really have the time to invest unfortunately.

Comment: ^ sounds like you want more than you can offer. I really suggest writing your own web service to display blob fields, its very easy to do, its .NET CLR friendly and you could share it with us on Stackoverflow. Dont be scared, I will help you do it if you want.

Comment: Devtron, could you point me in the direction of a tutorial or example web service?

Answer (score 2):

To scrape a web page, first figure out exactly which data you want to extract.

Visit the relevant pages with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) running, and look at the HTTP requests and responses that you get.

You can then write C# code that requests the relevant page and reads through the response, line by line, looking for lines that you're interested in.

If the web page is XHTML compliant, you can also parse it using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), but most web pages aren't.

Comment: How can we future-proof parser of this kind if remote webpage changes its structure? For example, my parser is searching for "music" tag, and they'd changed it to "musical". I see no way to deal with such things, but I am asking anyway.

Comment: Short answer is: you can't. Scraping HTML will always be inherently dependent on the structure of the page that you're scraping, and that structure is likely to change (even if the structure of the underlying data stays relatively stable).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.911tabs.com/ seems to have a large selection, and they appear to all be a variant of ASCII-art, so it would be relatively easy to write an HTML- or text-scraping routine.  They don't appear to use a very standardized format, however, so this might be more work than I think.

Comment: is screen scraping the best .NET solution out there? ummm, no.